# I'm trying to print the result of a function on a label

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I've managed to call the encrypt function from the Encrypt class, I've referenced the ids from kv file
now i want to print the result of the function on the label

.py file

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.animation import Animation
import string
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

Window.size = (360, 600)
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase


class CryptoMD(MDApp):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.Encrypt = Encrypt()
        self.title = 'Crypto'
        self.sm = ScreenManager()
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def animate_card(self, widget):
        anim = Animation(pos_hint={"center_y": 0.6}, duration=1)
        anim.start(widget)

    def animate_background(self, widget):
        anim = Animation(size_hint_y=1) + Animation(size_hint_y=0.5, duration=0.5)
        anim.start(widget.ids.bx)

    def set_text(self, Text, key):
        Text = Text.lower()
        key = key
        Key = int(key)
        obj = Encrypt()
        out_encrypt = obj.encrypt(Text,key)
#       self.root.ids.output.text = out_encrypt
```

```
   self.root.ids.output.text = out_encrypt
```

adding above line in  def set_text(self, Text, key):  should do it
but it shows an error message

ValueError: None is not allowed for MDLabel._text

```
class Encrypt():
    def encrypt(self, Text, key):
        Text = Text.lower()
        key = key
        Key = int(key)
        encrypted_message = ""

        for c in Text:
            if c in alphabet:
                position = alphabet.find(c)
                new_position = (position + Key) % 26
                new_character = alphabet[new_position]
                encrypted_message += new_character
            else:
                encrypted_message += c
        message = str(encrypted_message)
        print(message.upper())



    def decrypt(self, Text, key):
        Text = Text.lower()  
        key = key
        Key = int(key)
        encrypted_message = ""

        for c in Text:
            if c in alphabet:
                position = alphabet.find(c)
                new_position = (position - Key) % 26
                new_character = alphabet[new_position]
                encrypted_message += new_character
            else:
                encrypted_message += c
        message = str(encrypted_message)
        print(message.upper())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CryptoMD().run()
```

.kv file

```
#:kivy 1.11.1
#:import rgba kivy.utils.rgba


<Special@Screen>:

BoxLayout:

    #Special:
      #  id: special_gridlayout

    MDCard:
        id:card
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: [0.7, 0.8]
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        padding: [20, 10, 10, 20]
        spacing: 7

        BoxLayout:
            padding: [10, 10, 10, 10]
            orientation: 'vertical'

            MDLabel:
                text: "[color=000000] Caesar Cipher [/color]"
                text_size: self.size
                font_size: 35
                bold: True
                markup: True
                halign: "center"
                valign: "top"

            MDLabel:
                id: output
                text: "[color=000000] Output [/color]"
                text_size: self.size
                font_size: 35
                bold: True
                markup: True
                halign: "center"
                valign: "top"


        MDTextField:
            id: Text
            text: "A"
            auto_indent: True
            allow_copy: True
            multiline: False
            helper_text: "Enter Text..."
            helper_text_mode: "persistent"
            required: True

        MDTextField:
            id: key
            text: "1"
            input_filter: "int"
            helper_text: "Enter Key..."
            helper_text_mode: "persistent"
            required: True


        MDRoundFlatButton:
            id: encrypt_bt
            text: "Encrypt"
            size_hint_x: 0.6
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
            on_press:
                app.set_text(Text.text, key.text)

        MDRoundFlatButton:
            id: decrypt_bt
            text: "Decrypt"
            size_hint_x: 0.6
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
            on_press:
                app.Encrypt.decrypt(Text.text, key.text) if Text.text != "" else None


<BackgroundLayer@BoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        id: bx
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_y: 0.1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: rgba('#8A2BE2')
            RoundedRectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                radius: [0, 0, 40, 40]
```

Comment: Your `.encrypt()` method doesn't `return` anything, so there's nothing to be displayed on the label.

Comment: Oh! my bad, thanks a lot